# Editing font file to match glyph advances

Tags: fonts, glyph

I have an application that has access to certain fonts (with license to edit those). I want to create new fonts from the ones that I have by editing them in a way so that the glyph advances match with some other fonts that I don't have the license to use. This would enable me to use the edited font in place of the missing font, so that the sizing of the text would look similar (eg: the text would wrap at the same point).

*Now the question is, would editing the metrics (advance, font units per em etc.) of a font to match those of another one lead to any kind of distortions/undesired side effects?*

Answer (score 1):

> *"...the question is, would editing the metrics (advance, font units per em etc.) of a font to match those of another one lead to any kind of distortions/undesired side effects?"*

Most likely it would.

The `em` square is an important metric for each font. However, this alone does not determine the metric of each single glyph.

Unless the two fonts do not use the exact same relative widths for each respective glyph, there would occur "weird" looking spacings inside words and strings.

Imagine three `i`-s in one font adding up to take the same width as one `m`, but in the other font only two `i`-s required for the same font's `m`: how would you set the new metric then so that each line would wrap a the same spot? That's impossible for the general case covering all different combinations of strings...

Comment: So just to make sure I got it right, you are saying that editing that second font to make three  `i` s fit instead of the original two would lead to weird spacing within strings of text? Do you see any other way to handle the sizing variance between two fonts which are otherwise visually similar, so that wrapping also happens at same points?

Comment: I would not attempt this yourself unless you have some training in letterform design and a fair amount of time to do it (and re-do it)...or unless you want your result to look really crappy. Note, too, that there may be other attributes beyond the simple metrics that can affect character widths (hinting, device metrics).